# SQL/MySQL Query Assitance

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query to list the first and last names of all staff who have ever taught any of the same course as Kim (Staff_Fname) Cox (Staff_Lname) or have ever taught in the same room (Loc_id) as Kim Cox.

So far I have written this (and it's full of errors):

```
SELECT KimClasses.Course_Code, KimClasses.Course_Name, St2.Staff_Fname, St2.Staff_Lname
FROM
(SELECT St.Staff_id, CS.C_SE_id, C.Course_code, C.Course_name
FROM Staff St
JOIN CourseSection CS ON St.Staff_id = CS.Staff_ID
JOIN Location L ON CS.Loc_ID = L.Loc_id
JOIN Course C ON CS.Course_ID = C.Course_ID
WHERE St.Staff_Fname = "Kim"
    AND St.Staff_Lname = "Cox") KimClasses
JOIN CourseSection CS2 ON KimClasses.Course_ID = CS2.Course_ID
    AND NOT KimClasses.Staff_id = St2.Staff_id;
```

But I'm not sure on how I would include the part to list the staff that have taught in the same room.

Database schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTGV5.jpg

Comment: Post sample data and desired output in a tabular form or better yet as a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started...

```
 Select s.staff_fname,s.staff_lname
 from staff s join course_section cs
 on s.staff_if = cs.staff_id
 where cs.course_id in (select distinct s1.course_id from staff s1 join course_section sc1 where s1.Staff_Fname = 'kim' and s1.Staff_Lname = "Cox" )
 OR s.loc_id in  (select distinct s2.loc_id from staff s2 join course_section sc2 where s2.Staff_Fname = 'kim' and s2.Staff_Lname = "Cox" )
```